# Using NSIS Splice Function Causes Crash

Tags: parsing, installation, nsis

I am using the function [Splice](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Splice%3a_Cut_string_@_index_from_array_type_string) in my NSIS Installer.

**My Problem:** When I execute the below code the Splice function causes the installer to go into an infinite loop or crash it(it doesn't respond). Whats going wrong?

Am I using Splice wrong? If I cant use splice to split my string the way I want it to, **is there another function I could use to split a string?**

```
Section "Dummy"

    Push "user_lib_4d C:\12d\9.00\DTEI_Customisation\SURVEY_12d9\DTEI_Survey_User_Lib"  # "user_lib_4d C:/blah"
    Push "0"
    Push "user_lib_4d"
    Call Splice   # causes an infinite loop/crash

SectionEnd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I accidentally stumbled across the same trouble when using Splice function. But it took me only a little search on google to arrive at the right solution. The point is Splice is not meant for that. The `Push "user_lib_4d"` line is actually expecting a separator string. The solution is to use any of the actual string function meant for this purpose. There are [plenty out there](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Category%3aString_Functions) which makes it impossible to mention all here. You could rely on search substring, remove, or replace functions. The one I use and have had success is with [StrRep](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Another_String_Replace_%28and_Slash/BackSlash_Converter%29) by dirtydingus.

In  your case:

Section "Dummy"

```
Push "user_lib_4d C:\12d\9.00\DTEI_Customisation\SURVEY_12d9\DTEI_Survey_User_Lib"
Push "user_lib_4d"
Push ""
Call StrRep
Pop $R0 ;result

MessageBox mb_ok $R0
```

SectionEnd

Edit: for advanced operations you could use [StrStrAdv](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/StrStrAdv)